# PHP - posting checkbox values foreach record

Tags: php, html, checkbox

My html form has the following fields:

subscriberid - number input
product category - select option
typeofoutlet - 4 checkboxes.

Of this subscriberid is a static field. The html elements for product category and typeofoutlet are dynamically generated through a add record button.

[image]

I am trying to post the form data to mysql using PHP.  The following is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //connect to db
    $mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost', 'root','Abc@123def', 'tsl');
    $subscriberid = $_POST['subscriberid'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $brand = $_POST['brand'];
    $kirana = $_POST['kirana'];
    $chemist = $_POST['chemist'];
    $mall = $_POST['mall'];
    $online = $_POST['online'];

    foreach($category as $key => $value) { 
            //perform insert
            $query = "insert into hhpurchase (subscriberid, category,brand,kirana,chemist,mall,online) 
                    VALUES (
                        '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($subscriberid) ."',
                        '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($category[$key]) ."',
                        '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($brand[$key]) ."',
                        '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($kirana[$key]) ."',
                        '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($chemist[$key]) ."',
                        '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($mall[$key]) ."',
                        '". $mysqli->real_escape_string($online[$key]) ."'        

            )";
            $insert = $mysqli->query($query);
            if(!$insert) {
                echo $mysqli-> error;
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submission failed!')
                window.location.href='test.php';
                </script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submitted successfully!')
                window.location.href='test.php';
                </script>";
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close(); 
    }
```

While all the records gets recorded correctly, the data from 4 check boxes gets stored in the one line irrespective of number of lines of data that I have in the form.  The example output is as follows:

[image]

Now in the above image, the 1 under kirana is right, however, the 2 under chemist should be in row 2 but always gets posted in row 1.  However, if I have two rows and for both of which if I have selected the same option, they are getting posted correctly.

The HTML for checkboxes is as follows:

```
<label>Kirana</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="kirana[]" id="kirana" value="1">
<label>Chemist</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="chemist[]" id="chemist" value="2">
<label>Mall</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mall[]" id="mall" value="3">
<label>Online</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="online[]" id="online" value="4">
```

Comment: provide result of `print_r` of POST data after submit, pls

Comment: When checkbox is not checked  , the array is not created. So if you do not select kirana first and you select it on the second category . Kirana will have key 0 as if you picked him first.

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud  Thank you...so how do I force the creation of array...should I use a if condition to check for null and push 0?

Comment: You just have to force array index of each lines like : kirana[0], chemist[0] next category kirana[1],chemist[1] ...

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud  Thank you...instead of forcing to recursively building an array...I converted the checkboxes to select option with 0 and 1....which resolved my issue temporarily.  Thank you for your answer about `checkbox is not checked, the array is not created`...I can accept it if you post it as an ansewr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resume my comments here.

First of all if a checkbox is not checked the array is **not created**.

So  if I check only **kirana** on the first line and i check **mall** in the second.
Your code will provide this values:

```
$_POST['kirana'][0] = 1
$_POST['mall'][0] = 1
```

that's why you got trouble when you insert data.
An easy way to fix this and fit to your code is to force indexes on each line.

```
<!-- First Line -->
<input type="checkbox" name="kirana[0]" id="kirana_0" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chemist[0]" id="chemist_0" value="2" />
<!--Second line-->
<input type="checkbox" name="kirana[1]" id="kirana_1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="chemist[1]" id="chemist_1" value="2" />
```

Now if we examine another time the first example with this HTML

```
    //Now indexes are correct
    $_POST['kirana'][0] = 1
    $_POST['mall'][1] = 1
```

**Note** id attribute on html must be unique,else you must use class attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AlexandrePainchuad Thank you...I agree with the first point....however, since the checkboxes were getting created dynamically, providing them with unique id's may not be most appropriate...besides, while posting since I have to hardcode all the id's and values....it may not be an optimal solution.   I have agreed to your answer based on the indication that the array gets created only when the checkbox is checked.  Thank you.

Comment: @Apricot glad to help you